# Выводит только одно значение из БД

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите, я делаю запрос к БД, чтобы получить id пользователей к которым были отправлены сообщения, но вместо двух id из бд, я получаю только один.

```html
  $users_open_chat = DB::table('message')
      ->where('id_user_from','=',Auth::user()->id) //тут указываю "получить список сообщений с id равное id авторизованного пользователя"
      ->groupBy('id_user_to') // группирую все одинаковые id пользователей к которым были отправлены сообщения 
      ->get();
      
    
      
      foreach ($users_open_chat as $key => $row) {
        $users_all = $row->id_user_to; //тут должно вывестись числа 3 и 4 (т.е. те люди к которым были отправлены сообщения)
        
        $ids = explode(',', $users_all);
                
        $users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereIn('id', [$ids]) //вывожу список пользователей
        ->get();
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если брать Ваш код, то это должно выглядеть так:

```
$ids = DB::table('message')
      ->where('id_user_from', Auth::id()) 
      ->groupBy('id_user_to') 
      ->get()
      //создаем массив ids
      ->pluck('id_user_to');
      
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereIn('id', [$ids])
        ->get();
```

Можно проще

```
$users = DB::table('message')
        ->select('users.*')
        ->join('users','id','=','id_user_to')
        ->where('id_user_from', Auth::id())
        ->groupBy('id_user_to')
        ->get();
```